# In the calculation of precession of Mercury, why we can evaluate a definite integral using a contour integral

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, classical-mechanics, celestial-mechanics

In the calculation of Mercury using perturbation, we have to evaluate the integral:
$$
\delta \phi =-\frac{GMm}{2a^3}\sqrt{\frac{m}{2E}}\frac{\partial}{\partial J}\int^{r_{max}}_{r_{min}}\frac{r^3 dr}{\sqrt{(r-r_{min})(r_{max}-r)}} ;$$
then I found that in the textbook, it uses the contour integral:
$$
I =\int^{r_\max}_{r_\min}\frac{r^3 dr}{\sqrt{(r-r_{min})(r_{max}-r)}} =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u_1u_2}\oint\frac{du}{u^4\sqrt{(u-u_2)(u_1-u)}};
$$
where $u_1=1/r_{min}, u_2=1/r_{max}$.

I just wonder why it can be changed to contour integral. We know $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the singularities and the branch point, but why the integral along the real axis of $u$ are the two line one up the real axis and one below, I cannot figure out.

Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: You mean Mercury – "mercury" without a capital letter refers to the metallic element.

Comment: "the two line one up the real axis and one below" is ungrammatical and hard to understand. Perhaps you can express it mathematically?

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the correction. I mean why the integral along the real axis can be calculated by the contour integral contains the two singularity equivalently.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part. What I didn't understand was your description of the shape of the contour that I quoted.

Comment: @joriki The shape of the contour can be described as below: the contour consists a line segment parallel and close to the real axis but not touching it, extending to a small circle about the singularity u1, returning to a line segment parallel, close, and below the real axis in the negative direction, then to a small circle about the singularity u2.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry! It is the $r^3$. How to understand the transformation to the contour integral?